# Can our variables in set builder notation be inside sets themselves?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, graph-theory

I am wondering if it is proper to use set builder notation in the following way: {{$a,b$} | {$a,b$} $\in E$ and $u \in $ {$a,b$} }.
This expression came about because I was trying to define the degree of vertex $u$ in a graph. Mainly, I am wondering if it is acceptable to use sets themselves in set builder notation, which is done with {$a,b$}.

Comment: Your expression is OK, but $\{e \in E \mid u \in e\}$ would be easier to read.

Comment: If you must use set builder notation, @RobArthan 's comment is the way to do it. Words might be kinder to your reader:  the set of edges incident to vertex $u$. (when defining the degree be careful with either method if the graph may have loops.)

Comment: @EthanBolker: of course; and, to be even kinder to the reader, the OP should give the expression and the words.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks; with self-loops, what would be the reason why we would need to be careful? Are self-loops (an edge {$u,u$} ) not defined to augment the degree of vertex $u$?

Comment: Consider the graph with a single edge joining a single vertex to itself. Is the degree of the vertex $1$ or  $2$? In a picture two things leave the vertex  but there's only one edge. What definition do you want for the degree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written is not incorrect, but your notation should be as succinct, precise, and legible as possible.

I suggest the following change... assuming $G=(V,E)$ is an undirected graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$, you could define the set of all edges incident with vertex $u$ as follows:

$E_u = \{ e \in E \:\: | \:\: u \in e \}$

In addition, whenever possible, I recommend supplementing the notation with a verbal description to ensure you and the reader are on the same page.